# How to flatten a list of dicts and single items into a list where single items should be duplicated

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have this array:

```
import numpy as np

array_start = [{'Very Ripe': 5}, {'Ripe': 2}, np.nan]
```

I want to produce an array of the individual items and duplicate the `np.nan` values so that I end up with this array:

```
>>> array_end
['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
>>> array_end = [item.items() if isinstance(item,dict) else np.repeat(np.nan,2) for item in array_start]
>>> array_end
[dict_items([('Very Ripe', 5)]), dict_items([('Ripe', 2)]), array([nan, nan])]
```

This has gotten me somewhere, but then it seems more difficult to unpack the `dict_items` and the latter array (of `np.nan`s) within the `array_end` to produce the target `array_end`:

```
['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be in a single list comprehension? Don't let brevity be the enemy of functioning code.

Here's a way that uses two list comprehensions:

```
array_end = [list(*item.items()) if isinstance(item,dict) else np.repeat(np.nan,2) for item in array_start]
print(array_end)
# Output: [['Very Ripe', 5], ['Ripe', 2], array([nan, nan])]
```

We unpack the `dict_items()` objects into lists in the first list comprehension. Then, we have a list of lists (or numpy arrays), which we can run another comprehension on to flatten it.

```
array_final = [y for x in array_end for y in x]
print(array_final)
# Output: ['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each item in the `array_list`, check if it is a dict or not, and depending on that either duplicate the item if it's not, or extract all the dict items if it is. You have several options to do that using either

a simple loop with `list.extend`:

```
import numpy as np

array_start = [{'Very Ripe': 5}, {'Ripe': 2}, np.nan]

result = []
for element in array_start:
    if isinstance(element, dict):
        for item in element.items():
            result.extend(item)
    else:
        result.extend((element, element))
print(result)
# ['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

generator function:

```
def to_flat_list(array):
    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, dict):
            for item in element.items():
                yield from item
        else:
            yield element
            yield element

            
result = list(to_flat_list(array_start))
print(result)
# ['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

nested loops in a list comprehension:

```
result = [item 
          for element in array_start
          for pair in (element.items() if isinstance(element, dict) 
                       else [(element, element)])
          for item in pair]
print(result)
# ['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

[`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

flatten = chain.from_iterable
result = list(flatten((flatten(item.items()) 
                       if isinstance(item, dict) 
                       else (item, item) 
                       for item in array_start)))
print(result)
# ['Very Ripe', 5, 'Ripe', 2, nan, nan]
```

and probably some other ways. But these should suffice.